# Why Sigmoid function is so popular in every field of science?

Tags: probability, statistics, logistic-regression

I don't know if this is a silly question but still I couldn't resist my self from asking this.

I recently came to know about the standard sigmoid function while learning about logistic regression and neural networks. After that I found the same function in population growth modelling and Fermi-Dirac statistics. Is there something fundamental about this sigmoid function? Why is it so useful while tackling problems involving probabilities (given that we have other functions too)?

Comment: "The" sigmoid function? There are many: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function#Examples

Comment: “Why is it useful?” And “why is I popular?” don’t seem to have mathematical answers beyond “because it/they had/have properties that suit the applications.

Comment: [Have you read this question from stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/162988/why-sigmoid-function-instead-of-anything-else)?